# jOOQ how to use optional sorting

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have a query which selects persons from a table.

```
SelectConditionStep<PersonRecord> select = context
    .selectFrom(Tables.PERSON)
    .where(Tables.PERSON.ISDELETED.eq(false));

if(searchValue != null && searchValue.length() > 0){
    select.and(Tables.PERSON.LASTNAME.likeIgnoreCase(String.format("%%%s%%", searchValue)));
}
List<PersonRecord> dbPersons = select
    .orderBy(Tables.PERSON.LASTNAME, Tables.PERSON.FIRSTNAME, Tables.PERSON.ID)
    .limit(length).offset(start)
    .fetch();
```

This code works pretty well. Because I display the data in a datatables table I need to have optional / dynamic sorting capability. I did not find a solution so far.

Answer (score 7):

found the solution myself now:

```
Collection<SortField<?>> sortFields = new ArrayList<>();
sortFields.add(Tables.PERSON.FIRSTNAME.asc());

List<PersonRecord> dbPersons = select
        .orderBy(sortFields)
        .limit(length).offset(start)
        .fetch();
```